# what is the difference between the Riemann integral and the Stieltjes integral definition wise?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I know what the definition of a Riemann integral is from my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581728/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-riemann-integrable/1581731#1581731)
but now when I look up definitions of the Stieltjes integral all I find is that it is derived from the Riemann integral and instead of integrating $f(x) dx$ you are integrating $f(x) dg(x)$, I know how to integrate Stieltjes integrals what in terms of defining what it is, how do I state what a Stieltjes integral is without proofs?

Comment: The Riemann integral is a special case of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.  The one you get by using the special integrator $g(x) = x$.  There is a  Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral also: the Lebesgue integral with similar changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums)ik[i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral):

[image]

---

[image]

---

If I understand right, all you do pretty much is replace $x_{i+1} - x_i$ with $g(x_{i+1}) - g(x_i)$

---

Perhaps, I don't know what you mean. Are you looking for intuition? If so, we want to sometimes integrate

$$\int f(x) g'(x) dx$$

If g isn't differentiable (such as a [Cantor cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Application_to_probability_theory)), we have the Stieltjes integral:

$$\int f(x) dg(x)$$

which generalises Riemann integrals of the form $\int f(x) g'(x) dx$ to allow for non-differentiable g