# Is this the correct continous compounding equivalent to daily compunding of 90%?

Tags: calculus, finance

Find the rate of continuous compounding equivalent to daily compounding of 90%, if we assume that a year has 365 days.

P=principle
daily = $P(1+(\frac{0.9}{365}))^{365}$
continuous = $Pe^x$
$$(1+(\frac{0.9}{365}))^{365} = e^x$$
$$2.46=e^x$$
$$ln2.46=xlne$$
$$x=0.8989 \quad or \quad 89.89\%$$

Is $89.89\%$ continuous compounding equivalent to $90\%$ daily compounding?

Comment: When I use Wolfram Alpha I get 0.89889 which is pretty darn close to 0.9! I'd say the difference is due to rounding errors.

Comment: I could have checked on wolfram also, I am asking if my math is correct?

Comment: I'd think so (finance isn't my strong suit); I don't think there's a formal difference between the continuous and daily in this instance, but let someone more knowledgeable answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe answer and solution are correct. This is just algebra. You've already shown basic understanding of [advanced calculus concepts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581728/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-riemann-integrable) soooo.....

Btw, I think you should have said:

$A = P(1+(\frac{0.9}{365}))^{365\color{red}{t}}$
$A = Pe^{x\color{red}{t}}$

where $A$ denotes amount to owed to lender if $t$ under a certain type of compounding

Comment: I've taken a lot of math classes but this is the first time I am taking a math class focused on finance so I am still not used to finance terminology.

Comment: @idknuttin Try quant SE?

Comment: @idknuttin I get that, but you asked 'I am asking if my math is correct?' :P